# Consecutive cells with data in that resests after a blank cell

Tags: excel, reset

Basically our employees aren't allowed to work more than 13 days consecutivley, I would like to be able to have a cell that highlights how many days in a row a person has worked that resets after they have had a day off. Is this possibile?

Hours worked are in cells in a row, if they have a day off there will be a blank cell.

Answer (score 0):

With data in the first row, in **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

and in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(B1="",0,B1+A2)
```

copy **B2** across:

[image]

If all you want is a **count** of days then in **B1** enter **1** and in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(B1="",0,1+A2)
```

and copy across:

[image]